# I Want To Download Sub folder files in python

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I have to download MyBucket/bucket1/bucket1.1/bucket1.1.2/application.csv

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is a convenient way to call AWS API commands, including a copy command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://MyBucket/bucket1/bucket1.1/bucket1.1.2/application.csv .
```

If you wish to do it via boto3:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2') # Adjust as necessary
response = s3_client.download_file('MyBucket', 'bucket1/bucket1.1/bucket1.1.2/application.csv', '/tmp/application.csv')
```

See: [S3 — Boto 3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file)

Comment: Thank you for helping. I got error:- clientError: an error occurred (404)when calling the headobject operation:Not Found

Comment: This probably indicates that the object does not exist in the bucket you specified.